# Nested class of templated class with friend operator, compile error

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, nested-class

When I try to compile this (g++):

```
template<typename T>
struct A {

    struct B { };

    template<typename S>
    friend A<S>& operator +(A<S> const &, A<S> const &);
};

template<typename T>
A<T>& operator +(A<T> const &a, A<T> const &b) {
    A<T>::B *x;
    return a;
}

main() { }
```

I get

```
test.cpp: In function "A<T>& operator+(const A<T>&, const A<T>&)":
test.cpp:12:11: error: "x" was not declared in this scope
```

Why?

[disregard: if i don't include this line, stack overflow says i have too much code in my post when i save]

Comment: `B` is dependent type, use `typename A<T>::B *x;` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: `main() { }A`? That's not valid C++.

Comment: and you're using `S` in the declaration and `T` in the definition of your `operator+`

Comment: Pasting error. Fixed. (@Joachim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know that `A<T>::B` denotes a type so it tries to do multiplication there.

Use `typename A<T>::B *x;`

Comment: Thanks for the fix and the bonus explanation.